# Visual Studio Community doesn't allow me to login

Tags: login, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to getting Visual Studio Community working on my computer (both 2013, and 2015 RC). However, when trying to activate either version, I always come across the same error.

"The online service is not available. Please try again later."

[image]

or if I try to 'Add an account', I get the following error: "an error occurred while sending the request".

[image]

Yet the website reports it as being up, and I see little other mention of this problems (I've tried Googling the various terms, unless I'm doing something wrong there isn't any help out there).

I'm on a Windows 8 machine. I've checked for any hosts entries. I don't have a firewall running on my router or on my computer. I don't have an antivirus program running either. I've restarted my computer, reinstalled VS.

Any help?

Comment: Are you behind any proxy? Normally proxies can cause such issues.

Comment: No proxies, no.

http://i.imgur.com/9bCpxwv.png

Comment: Download fiddler and see if you can see if any http / https connection is failing and why

Comment: What Fiddler tells me: http://i.imgur.com/aTHbO7H.png http://i.imgur.com/LNYj2RL.png

`14:46:25:8675 fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to go.microsoft.com failed. System.IO.IOException Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
`

Comment: See http://www.telerik.com/forums/https-handshake-failed and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944280/fiddler-is-not-showing-https-traffic. This error is related to fiddler

Comment: Does nothing: `16:28:00:0320 Legacy compat applied for inbound request to go.microsoft.com
16:28:00:1110 fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to go.microsoft.com failed. System.IO.IOException Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
`

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2014/07/24/can-t-connect-to-visual-studio-online-from-any-version-of-in-vs-quot-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send-quot.aspx

Comment: I've tried the steps at your guide, and little to nothing has changed. I've decided to end my pursuit of getting it working for now. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far too late as a response, but this issue existed because of a fault within my install of Windows (other issues related to this was Windows Update being broken).

This fix for was to simply reinstall the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

Change the Visual Studio proxy settings in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

to

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2017. Based on this thread
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70622/unable-to-login-into-visual-studio-2017-with-micro.html
it can be worked-around by logging in via problem reporting function.
[image]
Clicking on `Report a Problem` will open a window which will ask you to log in. Logging in there often works even when using the button `Sign in` in the upper right corner doesn't.

Comment: Not sure why you were being downvoted. This answer is spot-on and solved my problem, where my 30 day trial license expired but the "update your license" dialog would not let me log in. (The login window simply went unresponsive.) I could circumvent this by quickly clicking on "Report a Problem" when starting VS before the dialog would block me from doing anything else. +1